# Facebook graph api for photos my page is tagged in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Page. I am using the graph api (page-id/photos) to get all the photos my page is tagged in. I am the admin of the page. I am using the access token with all the permissions including manage_pages. But the only photo that is returned in json is the page profile picture. Can Some One help me to receive all the photos my page is tagged in?
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=%257Bpage-id%257D%2Fphotos&version=v2.2
Thanks

Comment: are your sure there is other photos where your page is tagged in?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I myself tagged this page in photos using different accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the Issue. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/photos
The document reference is not clear. The end point is page-id/photos/tagged. 
Steps

1. get access token of the person with manage_pages permissions
2. get access token of the page using me/accounts endpoint/
3. get all tagged pictures using page-id/photos/tagged endpoint